# writing hebrew text in rust

Tags: rust, right-to-left, hebrew, left-to-right

i am making a CLI app in rust, and the app includes multiple languages. one of those languages is hebrew, which is a RTL language. when writing in hebrew, for example:

```
println!("קוד לדוגמא");
```

it comes out as

```
אמגודל דוק
```

which is the original message in reverse.

i know i can just write the text and reverse, and then it works, but i have a lot of text to write, and i don't want to have any side effects from this. is there any library or configuration in rust in order to write RTL text?

Comment: It seems to work just fine on the playground. What do you use as an output device (terminal...)? You may try `\u{202E}קוד לדוגמא` just for laughs, which includes the RIGHT-TO-LEFT-OVERRIDE unicode character.

Comment: i'm using debian, and i am using rustrover and vscode for the code, and both of them wrote this in reverse, even with the RTL override

Comment: It depends on your output device. Try running your program in gnome terminal or whatever comes with your OS. Some terminals support RTL/BIDI text, some don't (so sometimes you must reverse and sometimes you cannot reverse). You cannot tell which is the case with your terminal from within a program, there is no API. Note (1) there is a lot more to BIDI text than simple reversal and (2) you think that's hard? wait until you need to display Arabic on one of those non-supporting devices.

Comment: @throwawayaccount, can confirm this behavior in VSCode on GitHub Codespaces and on MacOS. However, the same terminal output (same tmux session) is rendered correctly (RTL) in MacOS-Terminal compared to VSCode (LTR). So it's definitely a output device issue, not Rust specific

Comment: @throwawayaccount if it's acceptable, try piping into fribidi. Haven't been doing that in a while but it used to solve this in a local manner

Comment: i forgot about this since this is a secondary account (long story short, i wrote a bunch of shit questions when i didn't know how to program, and at some point i got so much dislikes that stackoverflow removed my ability to ask questions, even though my current ones are at least okay) but it seems that emulating a terminal requires some sort of binary reading, so most text editors have this issue, but it can be solved just by making sure to not emulate a terminal, just write the output and input into a designated area.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that anything that emulates a terminal does this bug. This depends on the editor, but you should have to option to just display the result instead of emulate a commandline. on rustrover just go into your "run/debug configurations" and turn off "emulate terminal in output console". this also worked on other jetbrains products, but i haven't tested on all of them.